# Looking for a lighter editor, closed as not constructive, points on making it in scope?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

I've found a closed question of particular interest to me. The reason was that it's "not constructive".

> [What lightweight editor has autosave per keystroke, similar to intelliJ idea?](https://superuser.com/questions/401967/what-lightweight-editor-has-autosave-per-keystroke-similar-to-intellij-idea)
>
> Would love to use something lighter, but for web editing the autosave is key. Do not want to have to press ctrl + s again :)

What can we do to make this question constructive, so that it won't be closed anymore?

Comment: The question is soliciting software recommendations, which are off-optic here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For that question, there is no way to re-edit it in a way that it isn't asking for a program with a certain feature.

For a constructive question, you need to focus on what you need to do or what problem you are trying to fix. Not on what feature a program has. (Today it would be closed as "seeking product or tool recommendations")

In that view, look at the question again and try and address it from the point of view of using the program to do something.

> #### What lightweight editor has autosave per keystroke, similar to intelliJ idea?
>
> Would love to use something lighter, but for web editing the autosave is key. Do not want to have to press ctrl + s again.

So to the question, IntelliJ has autosave per keystroke, but it's not light enough. Now, recommend a tool that is lighter than IntelliJ because... why?

When the question is focussing on a feature search instead of the problem at hand, then it's a question that needs to be edited to be direct, or closed/deleted because it's out of scope.

Comment: As I don't know original intent of author, should I edit it to tell about what task I am solving, or should it be another question? Is there an official SU policy for that? (It seems like the second way is the right one, because there's a risk author will be back to fix his question, though it's unlikely.)

Comment: Would it be better to ask the question at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: If the question is the same as the original, ask it on the other site. If it's not, then you can re-ask it. But keep this answer in mind when writing it up.